# Go - Custom unmarshaler - string to float

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I consume a 3th party API that gives me the price as a string, there are 3 flavours:

```
//Input
[
    {"id": "A", "price": "123"},
    {"id": "B", "price": "123.5"},
    {"id": "C", "price": ""}
]

//Expected output

[
    A 123,
    B 123.5,
    C 0
]
```

I know i can add the `,string` part inside my struct but this will not handle order C. I have found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26800) github issue where this question is asked about int's. In there there is a [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nWl2toE2RAE) code that i altered a little bit to my needs.

If i change this to float64 instead of int i get an error with the log of order A that is now 0.

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Order.price of type float64
[{A 0}]
```

I thought that this `if string(data) ==  '""' {` part of the code will check for the empty string (case order C) if so: set to 0. But `"123"` is not `""`. The rest of the custom unmarshaler i understand apart from the part below. Can someone point me to the right direction?

```
p := (*float64)(foe)
*p = f
```

**The full code** [Also here](https://go.dev/play/p/-_BArOztsOj)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type StringToFloat float64

type Order struct {
    Id    string        `json:"id"`
    Price StringToFloat `json:"price"`
}

func (foe *StringToFloat) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == `""` {
        if foe != nil {
            *foe = 0
        }
        return nil
    }

    var f float64
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &f)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p := (*float64)(foe)
    *p = f
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonString := `[
        {"id": "A", "price": "123"},
        {"id": "B", "price": "123.5"},
        {"id": "C", "price": ""}
    ]`
    var orders []Order
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonString)).Decode(&orders); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(orders)
}
```

EDIT: comment @mkopriva

I adjusted the unmarshaler:

```
func (foe *StringToFloat) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    if string(data) == `""` {
        if foe != nil {
            *foe = 0
        }
    }

    n, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(data), 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    *foe = StringToFloat(n)
}
```

What gives me this output:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Order.price of type main.StringToFloat
[{A 0} {B 0} {C 0}]
```

Comment: `"123"` is not identical to `123`. One is a string the other a number. The content of the `data` variable is a JSON string. Unmarshaling into `float64` requires a JSON number. Instead of `json.Unmarshal(data, &)` you should just use `strconv.ParseFloat`.

Comment: You also have a quoted string, and `"` characters are not part of any number, so they must be stripped off.

Comment: @mkopriva i updated my post. I still can't get it to work within the unmarshaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type StringToFloat float64

type Order struct {
    Id    string        `json:"id"`
    Price StringToFloat `json:"price"`
}

func (foe *StringToFloat) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == "\"\"" {
        if foe != nil {
            *foe = 0
        }
        return nil
    }
    num := strings.ReplaceAll(string(data), "\"", "")
    n, err := strconv.ParseFloat(num, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *foe = StringToFloat(n)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonString := `[
        {"id": "A", "price": "123"},
        {"id": "B", "price": "123.5"},
        {"id": "C", "price": ""}
    ]`
    var orders []Order
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonString)).Decode(&orders); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(orders)
}
```

Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/cHjNQ447eX9

Things to note:

- The function signature of UmarshalJSON func needs to be exactly the same as given to be picked up by Decode. In your updated code `error` return type was missing
- `string(data)` gives `"123"` so the quotes need to be removed before `ParseFloat`
- `return nil` is required after string = `""` check so it dosent go further

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense (you're second bullit). I couldn't wrap my head around why `f, err := strconv.ParseFloat("3.1415", 64)` works inside the main function without  unmarshaler. And inside it does not.